# Laravel mostrar contenido dependiendo de si la consulta es vacia o trae registros

Tags: laravel

Hola quiero saber como puedo enviar un mensaje en la vista cuando la consulta traiga un valor NULL, estoy probando este codigo:

Consulta:

```
$productos['productos']= DB::table('productos')
                ->join('marcas','marcas.mar_id','=','productos.mar_id')                                           
                ->select('productos.pro_nom','marcas.mar_nom')
                ->where('productos.est_id','=',$id)
                ->paginate(10);
    
    return view('productos.activos', $productos);
```

activos.blade.php:

```
    @if ($productos->count())
    
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
    
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Marca</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    
        <tbody>

@foreach($productos as $producto)
<tr>
            <td>{{$loop->iteration}}</td>
            <td>{{$producto->pro_nom}} </td>
            <td>{{$producto->mar_nom}}</td>

        </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>

@else
<h1> No hay productos</h1>
@endif
```

Este codigo me devuelve este error:

```
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Call to a member function count() on array (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\
```

¿Como puedo lograr mostrar los registros o el h1 dependiendo del valor de la consulta?

Comment: $productos es un array, si lo que quieres es contar la cantidad de productos de la key `productos` entonces debes usar `count($productos['productos'])` , por otra parte el foreach necesita un plural y un singular

Comment: Podrías hacer un `@php dd($productos) @endphp` antes del `@if`? `first()` debería devolver un objeto, no un array. Tenés varias cosas mal, que ya te las mencionaron. Pero quiero estar seguro de que estás obteniendo lo que corresponde.

Comment: tenia el ->first() por un tema de prueba, pero la realidad es que va un ->paginate(10); por eso el foreach

Comment: Entonces editá tu pregunta y poné lo que estás usando. Sino estamos sacando todas conclusiones erradas.

Comment: ya la edite ahora esta como corresponde

Comment: Perfecto, probá igual lo que te dije más arriba, si el error sigue siendo el mismo algo raro hay. Porque `paginate()` devuelve un objeto, no un array.